# Error that can't be caught and doesn't stop program

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I am running a piece of code that is throwing an error in eclipse. The strange thing is that the logcat shows that after the error is thrown the program keeps running, furthermore the block of code is performing it's task correctly, and I am unable to catch the error. Is it possible that this is an eclipse bug? I have included my logcat below.

```
10-26 22:38:13.300: INFO/System.out(844):  Proxy Main Triggered URL:     http://api.discogs.com/master/39614
10-26 22:38:13.300: INFO/System.out(844): 1Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.300: INFO/System.out(844): 2Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.310: INFO/System.out(844): 3Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.310: INFO/System.out(844): 4Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.310: INFO/System.out(844): 5Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.320: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(844): Shutting down VM
10-26 22:38:13.320: WARN/dalvikvm(844): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001da28)
10-26 22:38:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.discog10/com.discog10.popUpActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.discog10.popUpActivity.onCreate(popUpActivity.java:82)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
10-26 22:38:13.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     ... 11 more
10-26 22:38:13.340: INFO/Process(90): Sending signal. PID: 844 SIG: 3
10-26 22:38:13.350: INFO/dalvikvm(844): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
10-26 22:38:13.350: ERROR/dalvikvm(844): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
10-26 22:38:13.640: INFO/System.out(844): 6Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.650: INFO/global(844): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
10-26 22:38:13.650: INFO/System.out(844): 7Proxy Main Triggered
10-26 22:38:13.650: INFO/System.out(844): Proxy Main Complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix the code which causes the NullPointerException at this line (or post it as part of your question):

```
com.discog10.popUpActivity.onCreate(popUpActivity.java:82)
```

Do you run several threads? IMHO It's highly unlikely that it is an bug in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to debug for android so I debug you putting println's in my code. For some reason the error was popping after a println that was not where it actually was. Any way your answer enabled me to find and fix the actual error. Thanks so much!

Comment: `For some reason the error was popping after a println that was not where it actually was.` That means you have to clean, rebuild and redeploy. You were running old code.